# Can I divide two equal vectors and assign 1?

Tags: vectors

I was reading a mechanics textbook where the following 3-step derivation is not convincing.[image]

In the left-hand side of the second step equation, both $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{r}}$ and $\vec{\dot{r}}$ are vectors right? There should have been a dot or cross there.

Assuming there was dot, can I cancel between $d\vec{r}$ in $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{r}}$ and $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$ thus getting $\frac{dV}{dt}$ ?

If my approach was totally wrong, please help me understand how to get the second equation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That should be a typo considering that he uses the same equation on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is the dot product, and what is happening is as follows

Suppose you are in an $N$ dimensional space, where $V: R^n \to R$ and $\vec{r} = (r_1, r_2,...,r_n)$

Hence, by definition, $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{r}} = \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial r_1}, \frac{\partial V}{\partial r_2}, ..., \frac{\partial V}{\partial r_n}\right)$$

Now,

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{r}} \cdot \dot{\vec{{r}}} = \sum \frac{dr_i}{dt}\cdot\frac{\partial V}{\partial r_i}$$

We then use the chain rule to simplify this to

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{r}} \cdot \dot{\vec{{r}}} = \frac{dV}{dt}$$